# Memory Management in C

Tags: c

I've just started learning C and haven't been doing any memory management up to now. Can anyone recommend a good guide/tutorial for memory management in C?

Comment: what do you mean by memory management? if you mean dynamic memory allocation and using pointers, there are plenty of guides on C pointers. If you mean OS Memory Manager, its a whole different worlds.

Comment: yeah, dynamic memory allocation

Comment: http://www.openismus.com/documents/cplusplus/cpointers.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the biggest thing to wrap your head around is storage and lifetime of variables in memory (stack vs heap). You can check out [WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Memory_management)'s treatment of this topic. I find it to be a gentler introduction to a lot of topics.

Answer (score -1):

Helps if you are more specific. Perhaps, this maybe of some help http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: That's not relevant to the question, and is totally beyond beginner level.